# Local event bus through view [Vue 2 cli]

Tags: vue.js

as you know, we can create a global event bus with the created events in the bus which is in main.js or even the events in the global, but how can I create a local event in parallel with the global event bus - on one page and all of its components

Comment: just do Vue.$emit in your component in addition to your event bus instance